Bootstrap Navbar Hamburger Menu is not collapsing
I am using Bootstrap v5.3 and I have added a navbar to my website. The problem I'm having is that the navbar hamburger icon is not collapsing when I click it on the mobile version of my website. Could someone please check if my code is correct? I really don't know what the problem is.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title> Title </title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-0pUGZvbkm6XF6gxjEnlmuGrJXVbNuzT9qBBavbLwCsOGabYfZo0T0to5eqruptLy"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,500;1,500&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">


    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
            
            <a
                href="#"
                class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">
                Logo
                </a>
                <button
                type="button"
                data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
                class="navbar-toggler"
                aria-controls="navbarNav"
                aria-expanded="false"
                aria-label="Toggle navigation"
                >
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

                <div 
                class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link active">
                                Home
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                About Us
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                Courses
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                Contact
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                Blog
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                
        </nav>



I used data-bs-toggle="collapse" but this did not work.

Your code works when I include the necessary JS and CSS files.

The problem is that you have loaded 3 libraries in Bootstrap 5.3.3: bootstrap.bundle.min.js, bootstrap.min.js and popper.min.js.
In 5.3.3 it is a conflict. So you should choose between "only bootstrap.bundle.min.js" or "bootstrap.min.js and popper.min.js".
What is the best option?
Both options are valid, but the choice depends on your specific needs and preferences:
Using bootstrap.bundle.min.js
•  Includes Popper.js: This file already includes Popper.js, which is required for certain Bootstrap components like tooltips and popovers.
•  Convenience: It's easier to include a single file, reducing the number of script tags in your HTML.
•  Less Error-Prone: Since Popper.js is included, you avoid potential issues with loading order or missing dependencies.
Using bootstrap.min.js + popper.min.js
•  Modularity: If you prefer to manage dependencies separately, this option allows you to include only what you need.
•  Flexibility: You can update or replace Popper.js independently of Bootstrap if needed.
•  Potential for Smaller File Size: If you don't need Popper.js for your project, you can exclude it, potentially reducing the overall file size.
Recommendation:
For most projects, using bootstrap.bundle.min.js is the simpler and more convenient choice because it includes everything you need in one file. This reduces the risk of errors and simplifies your setup.
If you have specific reasons to manage dependencies separately or need more control over the versions of Popper.js and Bootstrap, then using bootstrap.min.js with popper.min.js might be the better option.

You need to add the required CDNs as below. CSS CDN in the head of your HTML and scripts CDNs at the end of your body as described in Bootstrap


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0pUGZvbkm6XF6gxjEnlmuGrJXVbNuzT9qBBavbLwCsOGabYfZo0T0to5eqruptLy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
        
        <a
            href="#"
            class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">
            Logo
            </a>
            <button
            type="button"
            data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
            class="navbar-toggler"
            aria-controls="navbarNav"
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation"
            >
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

            <div 
            class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link active">
                            Home
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                            About Us
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                            Courses
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                            Contact
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                            Blog
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            
    </nav>



